# Get Video Element in iFrame HTML 5 Embed

Tags: html, api, video, iframe, youtube

i am trying to get the HTML5 video Element inside the new Youtube Embed.
If i try to access the iframe with the player.getIframe(), but i cant get deeper inside
the iFrame Html to access the  tag and element

My aim is to change a DOMAttribute of the video Element

I would be thankful for advise

Answer (score 0):

According to [Youtube IFRAME embed](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

you could get a reference of iframe embed via onYouTubePlayerAPIReady()

Also Youtube related DOMAttribute could be configured via playerVars parameter as stated below

> ```
> player = new YT.Player('player', {
>       height: '390',
>       width: '640',
>       videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
>       playerVars: {
>          listType:'playlist',
>          list: 'UUPW9TMt0le6orPKdDwLR93w'
>       },
>       events: {
>         'onReady': onPlayerReady
>       }
> });
> ```